# Detect end of line or end of string with Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find the Javascript regex to detect a keyword (any character) followed by either new line or end of string. This is my attempt:

```
.+(?:\n|$)
```

I'm not sure that the `$` can be used in the or condition. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

What I am trying to detect with the regex is a keyword follow by either (1) another keyword, or (2) nothing (therefore new line or end of string)

For example: the string "aaa" right before the new line it would be a match; the string "bbb" at the end of the string it would be a match as well.

Comment: There is no "end of line" character in JS, so nothing to catch with a regexp. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample inputs and what you expect the regex (not) to match.

Comment: That's going to match pretty much any line, '.' matches everything, you probably want something like  [a-z]+$ or however that is written in JS.

Comment: @BjörnNilsson how does your regex detect that the string is right before a new line?

Comment: Wouldn't `a.split('\n')[0].slice(-1)` give you what you want?

Comment: Usually a regex pattern handles $ as end of line, in that case it should work. Not sure how it works in JS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go: https://regex101.com/r/tP5eV8/2

```
/[a-z]+$/gm
```

g returns multiple matches and m is for multi line
$ matches new line

This only matches the last keyword of the line.
Here is one that matches one or several words separated by space and ending in a newline: https://regex101.com/r/zB9bS0/1

```
(?:(?: |^)([a-z]+))+$
```